# How to identify whether .exe file(Not Installed) is 64bit or 32bit using windows command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

Suppose one .exe file is store in you desktop. I want to identify using command prompt whether it is 32bit or 64 Bit exe image. Please help How to identify?

Comment: Not that simple, a .NET program in particular will have a 32-bit PE header but still run as a 64-bit program.  Just start it and look in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of methods:

- dumpbin (SDK Tools)
- looking for the first printable character after PE (L (0x14c) for 32 bits and p for 64 (0x8664)) by using a text editor
- PExplorer (sysinternals tool)
- file command (running inside Cygwin)